# What tag for questions that require code golfing to be valid?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

Some questions require some amount of golfing because they have a maximum byte limit or are answer chaining and require no more than x bytes added to the previous answer.

However, code golf is not the winning criterion.

What should these questions be tagged?

- [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)
- [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)
- [code-compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-compression)

Comment: Could you provide some examples of these challenges?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69930/paint-starry-night-objectively-in-1kb-of-code

Comment: @DJMcMayhem https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125397/create-the-slowest-growing-function-you-can-in-under-100-bytes/125487#125487

Comment: Maybe something like [tag:max-length]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Neither

Tags are about search-ability.  We want people to get relevant results when they search a tag.

Categorizing these as [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) is misleading if not false.  These types of questions are not code-golf and any person looking for code-golf questions would not want to see these. Plain and simple.

While these questions do technically impose a source restriction they should not be tagged [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) because thats not what restricted source is about.  Restricted source questions are about creating interesting puzzles by removing the ability to use all of the aspects of a language.  Most commonly size limits are put in place as a way to prevent people from obtaining arbitrarily large scores.  Since people searching for a tag are looking for challenges *about* that tag, the tag should be salient to the challenge for it to be applied.

We should also not make a new tag.  The new tag would add nothing.  I cannot imagine a situation where someone would want to search for questions with this feature.  Its not a style of question and the questions would be a largely random selection of [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) questions.  Its like having a tag for challenges that ban builtins.  We don't need to categorize every aspect of a question, just the ones people might search for.

Answer (score 0):

[restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)

From the wiki for [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf):

> Code-golf is a competition to solve a particular problem in the fewest bytes of source code
>   ...
>   If source code length is not the primary scoring criterion, consider using another tag instead.

In these challenges, source code length is not the primary scoring criterion; rather, it is simply an additional restriction that affects validity not scoring.

From the wiki for [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source), however:

> Imposes a restriction on the source code used to solve the challenge

Generic, but describes exactly what's going on here.

[code-compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-compression) hasn't been used anywhere and sounds more like actually compressing (like gzip) source code in some way, so I don't think it's a good fit.